# XML Escape Characters in Java

Tags: java, xml

I have an object which I write to an xml. The xml has escape characters like "&", "<" etc. Now before I process this xml I want a utility to escape these special characters so that the resultant xml has & followed by "amp;" for "&" and "&" followed by  "lt;" for "<". I tried StringUtils, XMLWriter and few more but they convert the "<" in opening and closing tags as well which I dont want. I only want "<" in the attribute values to be replaced. Please help.
Example;

I have the input xml as this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<personName><firstName>Sam & Pat </firstName>
<sal> > than 10000 </sal>
</personName>
```

And the expected xml should be `

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<personName><firstName>Sam &amp; Pat </firstName>
<sal> &lt; than 10000 </sal>
</personName>
```

If I am using StringUtils, it converts all the "<" characters like this

```
&lt;sal&gt; &lt; than 10000 &lt;/sal&gt;
```

**EDIT:**  I can't actually use JaxB. I am using FreeMarkerTemplate to do this. Here is the code .

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".tmp");
try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(tempFile)) {
freeMarkerConfig.setOutputEncoding(UTF_8);
    Template template = freeMarkerConfig.getTemplate(templateName);
    template.process(data, writer);
}              `                                                                                                    
The resultant file which get created should have the handled escape characters.
```

Comment: Add a concrete example of what you want to achieve. Input and Output. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hi, I have added the example.

Comment: IMO After reading through this thread I believe your source should be responsible for sending a valid XML file. You can encode, escape the data as you wish, but a valid XML structure should not be your concern.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Apache Commons Lang Library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) for escaping the characters:

Example:

```
    String escapeString1 = "Sam & Pat ";
    System.out.println("Escaped : " + StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml11(escapeString1));

    String escapeString2 = " > than 10000";
    System.out.println("Escaped : " + StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml11(escapeString2));
```

Output:

```
Escaped : Sam &amp; Pat 
Escaped :  &gt; than 10000
```

Comment: StringEscapeUtils is fine to use if its just a string. But using this api for xml string converts every occurrence of '<' and '>' which makes it a malformed xml. Example :-     &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
&lt;personName>
         &lt;firstName>Sam &amp; Pat &lt;/firstName&gt;
&lt;/personName&gt;
&lt;sal&gt; &lt; than 10000 &lt;/sal&gt;

Answer (score 0):

You can use JAXB for the XML generation. Annotate your Model-Class with @XmlRootElement

Then you can use JAXB for marshalling the XML-Object:

```
try {
  JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);

  Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
  m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

  Person object = new Person();
  object.setPersonName("Sam & Pat");
  object.setSal("> than 10000");

  m.marshal(object, System.out);
} catch (JAXBException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The output will be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<person>
    <personName>Sam &amp; Pat</personName>
    <sal>&gt; than 10000</sal>
</person>
```

Comment: I cant use JaxB as we have to use FreeMarkerTemplate to generate the xml file based on a *.ftl template. I have added the code above for that. I cant find any any way to achieve with freemarker.

Answer (score 0):

Using `CDATA` will fix your problem.

Such as `<![CDATA[abc]]>`

Comment: I am not sure how to use CDATA as we get XML from the client and we cannot change it. Can you please elaborate this?

Answer (score 0):

You can include XML special characters in XPL. XPL has exactly the same structure as XML, but allows the special characters in text fields. http://hll.nu/